# ArcMap MXD will open on one computer but not any others?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, mxd

I have an MXD which I use on 10.2 at one office and it works fine, all layers there, no errors, data links fine.  The MXD lives on a shared LAN and is launched from there.

If that MXD is launched on the same LAN from another computer (also running 10.2) I get an error message that the file does not contain a valid arcmap document.

I have also tried copying the MXD and opening it locally on a different computer instead of across the LAN and get the same error.

I have also tried launching it from a 10.3 ArcMap install on a different computer but get the same error.  No matter which computer I try I can not get it to launch the MXD except on the initial computer.

I believe all these machines are running the same license level.

The text of the error message is:
[image: ArcMap Error]

Here is a link to dropbox with a zip of the MXD document:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/u2b5rjmhc93g7gc/TOC%20Current%20Template.zip?dl=0

Any ideas why this MXD is unhappy?

Comment: Does the first PC (which opens the MXD successfully) have any non-Esri ArcGIS extensions installed which the other machines don't have? I don't recall ever seeing this with ArcGIS 10+ but in the old days if you saved an Arcview project on a machine that had certain extensions installed, other machines which didn't have those extensions couldn't open it.

Comment: Is there anything different about the windows installations? Have you tried MXD doctor?

Comment: Do you get different results if you create a new MXD (File > Save As)?

Comment: The mxd opens in 10.4

Comment: I'd wonder about antivirus software or something else in the network copy mechanism somehow corrupting the MXD.

Comment: it opens for me on 10.3.1 and 10.4.1

Comment: I have run MXD Doctor on it, but it wouldn't even load the file.   As for third party plugins, I don't believe the PC that made the file has any installed, but I'll check next time I am working on it.  A save-as didn't provide a version that opens.  Really puzzling considering how it seems to open for others using 10.3.1 and 10.4.1, unfortunately the office all runs on 10.2 installs.